# String - get string behind the specified substring

Tags: java, string, substring

I have for example these lines:

```
af asf af dassfdfsdf a dfa sd<text:text which i need to store
xycCYXCYXCaAdadad<text:text which i need to store
56afdasfaaaaaa54554 ewrt<text:text which i need to store
```

How can I get the part of each line behind `<text:` string?

Comment: You should you regex in order to substract the substring using the delimiters you want, for instance in this case: `'<text'` Doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
String line = "af asf af dassfdfsdf a dfa sd<text:text which i need to store";
int pos = line.indexOf("<text:");
if (pos > 0) {
    line = line.substring(pos+6); // 6 is the length of your "<text:" marker
}
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/OzVny2).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "af asf af dassfdfsdf a dfa sd<text:text which i need to store";
    String result = str.substring(str.indexOf("<text:")+"<text:".length());
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

```
text which i need to store
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String result = new String(str.substring(0,str.indexOf("<text:")));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@gaffcz,....

Try below code once

String str = "af asf af dassfdfsdf a dfa sd<text:text";
int lastIndex =     str.lastIndexOf("<text:text");
str = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
System.out.println("str : "+str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`String a ="af asf af dassfdfsdf a dfa sd<text:text";
System.out.println(a.subSequence(0, a.lastIndexOf("<text:text") != -1 ? a.lastIndexOf("<text:text"): a.length()));`

Francesco